.NET 8: Developer Verification Error During App Store Review
I’m developing an app on .NET8 for macOS and encountered an issue during App Review with feedback:
"An error showed upon launch. The app cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified. This may be due to an issue with your app’s Gatekeeper conformance."
Additionally, the provided screenshot showed this message:
"Application is damaged and can't be opened. Delete and reinstall from App Store."
Here’s the process I follow to create the package:

Build the application.
dotnet build {SolutionFileName} --configuration Release
Sign it using the following command:
codesign --force --verify --verbose --deep --options runtime --timestamp --entitlements ../Entitlements.plist -s '3rd Party Mac Developer Application: [ID]' Demo.app
Create the package using this command:
productbuild --component Demo.app /Applications --sign '3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: [ID]' Demo.pkg
After installing the app from TestFligt it doesn’t show the errors.

The Entitlements.plist file contains the following keys and values:
<key>com.apple.application-identifier</key>
    <string>[ID].com.demo.appc</string>
    <key>com.apple.developer.team-identifier</key>
    <string>[ID]</string>   
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.bookmarks.app-scope</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-jit</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-dyld-environment-variables</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.disable-library-validation</key>
    <true/>

The project file snippet includes the following configuration for the release build:
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">  
    <OutputPath>bin\Release</OutputPath>   
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <NoStdLib>true</NoStdLib>
    <UseSGen>false</UseSGen>
    <UseRefCounting>false</UseRefCounting>
    <TlsProvider>Default</TlsProvider>        
    <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>    
    <TrimMode>partial</TrimMode>
    <RunAOTCompilation>false</RunAOTCompilation>    
    <EnablePackageSigning>true</EnablePackageSigning>
    <CodeSigningKey>3rd Party Mac Developer Application:[ID]</CodeSigningKey>
    <EnableCodeSigning>True</EnableCodeSigning>
    <CreatePackage>false</CreatePackage>    
    <PackageSigningKey>3rd Party Mac Developer Installer:[ID]</PackageSigningKey>
    <Profiling>false</Profiling>
    <CodeSignProvision>provfile</CodeSignProvision>
    <CodeSignEntitlements>Entitlements.plist</CodeSignEntitlements>    
    <LangVersion>default</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>

When I run the command:
security find-identity -vp macappstore
I get the following output:
5) "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: [ID]" (Missing required extension)
6) "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: [ID]" (Missing required extension)
